# Nested SQL Statements2

Tags: sql, sql-server

What tables are present in this code?

```
SELECT
    ProjectUID, 
    ProjectName, 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         MSP_TimesheetPeriod.PeriodName AS PeriodName, 
         MSP_TimesheetPeriod.PeriodUID AS PeriodUID, 
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
              MSP_TimesheetLine.TimesheetLineUID,
              MSP_TimesheetActual.TimeByDay AS TimeByDay,    --
              SUM(MSP_TimesheetActual.PlannedWork) AS PlannedWork, 
          FROM 
              dbo.MSP_TimesheetLine
          LEFT OUTER JOIN 
              dbo.MSP_TimesheetActual ON MSP_TimesheetLine.TimesheetLineUID = MSP_TimesheetActual.TimesheetLineUID) AS TimesheetLineData 
     INNER JOIN 
         dbo.MSP_TimesheetLine ON MSP_TimesheetLine.TimesheetLineUID = TimesheetLineData.TimesheetLineUID) AS MSP_TimesheetLine_UserView
INNER JOIN
    MSP_TimesheetLine_OlapView AS ov ON MSP_TimesheetLine_UserView.TimesheetLineUID = ov.TimesheetLineUID
```

Comment: Search with prefix `dbo`.

Comment: Hint:  `FROM` clause.

Comment: What's the question? I mean, they are three tables: `dbo.MSP_TimesheetLine` (twice), `dbo.MSP_TimesheetActual`, and `MSP_TimesheetLine_OlapView`.

Comment: @TheImpaler u aswer it, thks

Comment: @GordonLinoff: and `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` , too ... :-)

Comment: @manso.andre At the risk of being pedantic, also realize that they may not be tables but rather VIEWS as well in which case we can't tell you what the tables are without seeing the VIEW definitions.